# Two fixed columns bootstrap

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with my layout where I want to use the bootstrap css framework.
This is my layout so far:

[image]

(I've zoomed out to make clear what I mean)

This is my html markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <p>Data .....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div id="iframe">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <p>Data ....</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <p>Data ....</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <p>Data ....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the left of the page I want to show data and on the right I want to show an iframe in that image.
(When you click on a link in the left section it will load on the right)
But the data on the left only starts at the end of the image.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use this structure if I understand well what you want to do:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <p>Data ....</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span12">
                <p>Data ....</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span12">
                <p>Data ....</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div id="iframe">
            data
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am doing here is to create to rows of 6(half layout), and in the left one create rows of 12 (total layout), so it will use the whole left column.

Cheers,
Rafa

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfect! Do you know how I can make sure on the left column is scrollable? So that the image is staying in that position.

Comment: Set the the first row's height to the height of the image and `overflow-y=auto`